# If $f(x)>0$ for every rational $x$, does it imply $f(x)>0$ for all real $x$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. If $f(x)>0$ for every rational $x$, does it imply $f(x)>0$ for all real $x$? Prove or give a counterexample.

Since the statement with "$\ge$" instead is true, I assume this one is false. But I don't know how to prove it. Any suggestions?

Comment: E.g. $f(x)=(x-\sqrt 2)^2$.

Comment: $f(x)=\sin^2(x-\sqrt2)$. I do like SMM's example better (for the purposes of proving the claim) given that my claim requires the somewhat non-trivial fact that $1,\sqrt2$ and $\pi$ are linear independent over $\Bbb{Q}$. I just wanted to add an example where strict inequality is violated for infinitely many irrational numbers.

Comment: @SMM How is your example a counterexample to the given statement ? isn't that function positive for all x in $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas It is $0$ in $\sqrt 2$.

Answer (score 1):

What about

$$f(x)=1+\sin\left(\frac x \pi\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Take
$$f(x)=|x-\pi|$$

$$f(\pi)=0$$

$f$ is continuous at $\Bbb R$  and

$$f(\Bbb Q)\subset (0,+\infty)$$